# Why this php query does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

So I am making highscore system, for my unity game, using mysql, php.

For get highscore info stored in DB, I wrote like, (DB has 'score', 'name' column, but not 'rank' column name)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, score, name, CASE\n"
        . " WHEN @prev_value = score THEN @rank_count\n"
        . " WHEN @prev_value := score THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1\n"
        . "END AS rank\n"
        . "FROM BBR\n"
        . "ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $min, $max";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$info = "";
while($found = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $info = $info .'@'. $found['name'] .':'. $found['score'] .':'. $found['rank'];
}
echo $info;
```

and in unity, I receive this info and split to each string.

`string[] score = serverHighScores[x].Split(':');`

But this work at score[0] (name), score[1] (score) well, but does not work at score[2] (rank).

Why? How should I fix? 
Thanks.

---

This query is

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT id, score, name, CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = score THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := score THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
END AS rank
FROM BBR
ORDER BY score DESC
```

and this works well in phpmyadmin SQL.

Comment: Do you need `\n` in your query?

Comment: @IswantoSan Its just php string connection. No related with mysql.

Comment: Try to print `serverHighScores[x]` content

Comment: @IswantoSan printed, but well received name and score, but does not show rank info. Its like this, Found HighScores: Cody Shoff
:96:

Comment: What is the difference between `@prev_value = score` and `@prev_value := score`? Try to add else in your case when expression

Comment: So at above code, [END AS rank] this stores rank info to 'rank' temporary column, only generated when queried maybe? So how to toss this info to php and unity?

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for question related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read a tag description before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write the query something like this:

```
SELECT b.id
     , b.name
     , @rank_cnt := IF(@prev_score = b.score,@rank_cnt,@rank_cnt+1) AS rank
     , @prev_score := b.score AS score
  FROM BBR b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT @rank_cnt := 0, @prev_score := NULL) i
 ORDER BY b.score DESC, b.id DESC
```

NOTE: The behavior we observe with this query is *not* guaranteed. The MySQL Reference manual specifically warns against using user defined variables in this manner. But the behavior we observe (at least with MySQL 5.1 and 5.5) is consistent.

It's important that the assignment of `@prev_score` be done AFTER the comparison, that's why the columns are ordered in the SELECT list the way that they are.

I don't think the assignments within the CASE expression (the way it is in the query in the question) "work" the way we'd expect them to. I think it has to do with the order of operations that MySQL performs. I've always had the result of an expression assigned to a user defined variable in the SELECT list, as shown above.

The expression **`IF(@prev_score = b.score,@rank_cnt,@rank_cnt+1)`** could be replaced with an equivalent `CASE` expression:

```
  CASE WHEN @prev_score = b.score THEN @rank_cnt ELSE @rank_cnt+1 END
```

Note that the expression is returning a value, it's not attempting to do an assignment.

I prefer to have the user defined variables initialized within the statement, not dependent on separate `SET` statements. In this case, we're not really concerned with what's returned by the inline view `i`, except that we want it to return exactly one row (because of the JOIN operation)... we're really more interested that the inline view query gets materialized *before* the outer query runs, so that the variables are initialized when the outer query runs.

Also, I added another expression to the ORDER BY, so that the results are more deterministic.

... (add link to applicable section of MySQL Reference Manual regarding warnings about user defined variables)

---

The **`mysql_`** interface functions are *deprecated*.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO` interface instead.

Comment: Thx for long reply. But my issue is, why 'rank' info does not fetched by php code above?

Comment: Oh Thanks!! I just followed this SQL query, and the same above php code can fetch rank info! and works well in unity.

Comment: Origin query I posted at question also can show the 'rank' column well in DB's phpmyAdmin's SQL.  Problem was at above php code, .$found['rank'];  did not work.

Comment: Aha, I don't know well about SQL query syntax, but thx to let me know.